# Why hasn't there been a new podcast episode?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I really enjoy the Stack Overflow podcast, but there hasn't been one for a while. When can we expect the team at SO HQ to pod more casts?

Comment: They did a podcast with/about Jon Skeet. What more can they do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a 1 year Hiatus, [the Stack Overflow podcast is back](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/15/the-stack-overflow-podcast-is-back/), albeit with a new set of hosts.

> We’ve got three new hosts:
>
> Ben Popper, the director of content here at Stack (that’s me)
>   Sara Chipps, the director of Public Q&A at Stack, a veteran developer, and
>   Stack user number #4140
>
> Paul Ford: a writer and technologist who serves as CEO of Postlight, a
>   digital product studio
>
> We’ll be chatting about what it’s like to work in software
>   development, how folks can learn to code, and the way in which
>   computer programming is influencing business, culture, and society.

You can find it on [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/episode/39yK8Lc3Zk0j2JJdv2W9lT), [Overcast](https://overcast.fm/+UwBrtOquA) or via the [RSS feed](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3).

Comment: Half a year back, I would have commented: "oh nice, didn't know about the podcast, curious to listen into". Now, my first reaction is "interesting priorities they have these days". Not sure if I will ever be able to react positively to anything that the SE com folks do, even when it is something positive.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sure you realize there are many people working in an organization that work on different thing. It's not because there's a big mess with the CoC that everyone else needs to stop working..

Comment: @IEatBagels Well, that second name on that list ... if I would be the CEO of SO /SE Inc ... I would want my communications director to spend here time *not* with podcasts these days. I would rather work with her all day and night long to understand why communication is going so wrong lately, etc. pp. OK, seriously: in the end, this is bad timing. I assume the podcast was produced weeks ago. Well, I hope that. If it was produced during the last 2 weeks, I would say: some people got their priorities really really wrong.

Comment: I agree with @ghostcat. The Monica Cellio  vs. Sara Chipps controversy has left a bad taste in my mouth such that I don't really want to listen to this...used to really enjoy this podcast. Suggest maybe swapping Sarah for someone else for now.

Comment: When Paul Ford is not a part of the podcast then the show is extremely boring...just drones on.  All the voices sound the same when he isn't there. The show needs more viewpoints.

Answer (score 12):

The podcasts, in their current format, are a whole lot of work for something that (lately) is essentially 'meh'. We talk about the company news, Jay David & Joel have a good dynamic, but we've got to be honest that it has come pretty far from the early days when recording a new podcast was *the best way* to get people hooked on *our* enthusiasm.

There's also scheduling issues:

- I wouldn't wish Joel's schedule on anyone. I really mean that.
- David and Jay are kinda where Joel was a few years ago, which is another schedule I wouldn't wish on anyone
- Producing the podcast, especially if there's a guest, increasingly requires luck, fairy dust or magic in order to happen (did I mention scheduling?)

That's not to say that there won't be new episodes, or that you've heard the last of Joel David & Jay, but we're looking at a new format that we should be able to keep up with, and one that's more about *you* than it is us.

Maybe we could interview people actively giving their time on the site, maybe we should be talking more about issues programmers have to contend with, maybe we should reach out to people you love to follow on Twitter and get an AMA going on Twitch. Maybe we could, you know, spend more time talking about [our other sites, too](https://stackexchange.com), like we used to.

In other words, let's make it a *little* about us (we'll always talk about new stuff or contentious stuff), but mostly about you.

This is one of those things that [Juan is going to be picking up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network) in the coming weeks or months; he'll have some more when plans solidify. In the meantime, if you have format recommendations or ideas, just tag 'em [podcast](/questions/tagged/podcast) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and we'll respond to them.

Comment: That's interesting Tim and thanks for the detailed response. Sounds like you have some good plans in the works. I would say though that one thing I really like about the current Podcast (aside from some of the fun/zaniness) is hearing the depth to which you debate changes to the site. It's really insightful and inspiring. So, personally I hope to hear that continue.

Comment: One of the ways that Stack Overflow en español has grown tighter as a community is [through their Webcasts](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg/videos).  In them, community members are interviewed on a topic.  They also answer "live" questions from other viewers.  It's a great way for people to see each other and learn from each other.  Maybe that's something we could try on other network sites.

Answer (score 10):

The answer can be found [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackPodcast/status/992068013854740480):

> Wondering why there's not been new episodes lately? We've been a little busy...
>   Introducing Teams!

So I guess when work on Teams is wrapping up, they'll start doing podcasts again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that they finally started another podcast in April 2019: [Unicorn Meta Zoo #1: Why another podcast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326560)

Comment: That's quite a different format than the old HQ podcast, though. It's clearly a different team with a different mission and consequently a different name for the podcast.

Comment: @tripleee yeah that's true